# Python : How to make a quiz and check if the answer is correct?

Tags: python, input

I'm taking a computer science course and I recently took a test and there was a question whose answer I did not know  and I want to know how to do it.

The Question/problem was Ask the user 7 questions. Then check how many were correct and then give a percentage. I am familiar with input and operators and variables but I do not understand how to check if the answer the user inputed was correct and how to calculate how many were correct and how many were incorrect

Comment: We will not do you homework for you. Try to do it yourself, and ask help with a specific issue in your code which you can't solve.

Comment: `if raw_input("what is 5+7=?") == "12": print "Correct-o-rama!"` ...

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (pseudo-code)?

```
qa = [
    ('Q1', 'A1'),
    ('Q2', 'A2'),
     ]
num_correct = 0

for q,a in qa:
    user_answer = raw_input(q) 
    if user_answer == a:
        num_correct += 1

print 'Total questions:', len(qa)
print 'Total correct:', num_correct
```

You should be able to find out the rest.

Comment: Why not map the questions and answers to a dictionary instead of using tuples?

Comment: Sure. Unless you want to preserve order.

Comment: Well if you get each answer by key, that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I was thinking about preserving the order of the questions. Whatever works.

Comment: Well, for a tuple that would be important, but with a dictionary, that does not matter. If you search by key, you have no need for order.

Comment: I don't think I understand you. Maybe you can provide the code the way you would do it.

Comment: Na, its fine.  What you doing is pseudo code anyways. The OP should be able to go on from what you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've Done It, Code of What I Did Below:

```
q1=int(input("What Is 5+1 "))
if q1==6:
    print ("Correct")
    corr1=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 6")
    corr1=int(0)

q2=int(input("What Is 6+9 "))
if q2==15:
    print ("Correct")
    corr2=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 115")
    corr2=int(0)
        
q3=int(input("What Is 54+4 "))
if q3==58:
    print ("Correct")
    corr3=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 58")
    corr3=int(0)

q4=int(input("What Is 43+9 "))
if q4==52:
    print ("Correct")
    corr4=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 52")
    corr4=int(0)

q5=int(input("What Is 67+9 "))
if q5==76:
    print ("Correct")
    corr5=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 76")
    corr5=int(0)

q6=int(input("What Is 64+14 "))
if q6==78:
    print ("Correct")
    corr6=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 78")
    corr6=int(0)

q7=int(input("What Is 44+3 "))
if q7==47:
    print ("Correct")
    corr7=int(1)
else:
    print ("Wrong, The Answer Is: 47")
    corr7=int(0)

correct=corr1+corr2+corr3+corr4+corr5+corr6+corr7
print("You Scored %s/7" %(correct))

per=int(correct/7*100)

if per>=50:
    print("Congratulations You Passed With A %s Percent" % (per))
else:
    print("Oh No You Did Not Pass The Test And Scored A %s Percent, Try Harder Next Time!" %(per))
```